# UIWebView doesn't display background-color property when in PaginationMode in iOS 10.3.2

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiwebview

I have used an UIWebView with PaginationMode UIWebPaginationModeLeftToRight in an iOS app and the app was working perfectly. But the recent update of iOS i.e. iOS 10.3.2 stopped working **background-color** property, although the  **color** property is working. I tried to solve the issue many ways like setting UIWebView's opaque property to NO and different way to assign background color to body tag. As I am unable to solve the issue, I come to here to ask about the issue. I believe somebody will help me solving the issue. My sample code to test is as below:

```
//
//  ViewController.m
//  UIWebViewBackground


#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController () <UIWebViewDelegate>
{
    UIWebView *webview;
}
@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    
    self.title  =  @"UIWebView Demo";
    
    if(webview == nil)
        {
            webview = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame: self.view.bounds];
            webview.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;
            
            [self.view addSubview:webview];
            [self.view layoutSubviews];
            
            CGFloat width = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.width;
            [webview setPageLength:width];
            webview.delegate = self;
            webview.scrollView.pagingEnabled = YES;
            
            [webview setPaginationMode: UIWebPaginationModeLeftToRight];
            [webview setPaginationBreakingMode:UIWebPaginationBreakingModeColumn];
            
            // load the skeleton HTML into webview
            NSString *myHTML = @"<htm><body style=\"background-color:green; color:red;\"><h1>UI WebView</h1><br/><h1>UI WebView</h1><br/><h1>UI WebView</h1><br/><h1>UI WebView</h1><br/><h1>UI WebView</h1><br/><h1>UI WebView</h1><br/><h1>UI WebView</h1><br/><h1>UI WebView</h1><br/><h1>UI WebView</h1><br/><h1>UI WebView</h1><br/><h1>UI WebView</h1><br/><h1>UI WebView</h1><br/><h1>UI WebView</h1><br/><h1>UI WebView</h1><br/><h1>UI WebView</h1><br/><h1>UI WebView</h1><br/><h1>UI WebView</h1><br/><h1>UI WebView</h1><br/><h1>UI WebView</h1><br/><h1>UI WebView</h1><br/><h1>UI WebView</h1><br/><h1>UI WebView</h1><br/><h1>UI WebView</h1><br/><h1>UI WebView</h1><br/><h1>UI WebView</h1><br/><h1>UI WebView</h1><br/><h1>UI WebView</h1><br/><h1>UI WebView</h1><br/><h1>UI WebView</h1><br/><h1>UI WebView</h1><br/><h1>UI WebView</h1><br/><h1>UI WebView</h1><br/><h1>UI WebView</h1><br/><h1>UI WebView</h1><br/><h1>UI WebView</h1><br/><h1>UI WebView</h1><br/></body></html>";
            
            [webview loadHTMLString:myHTML baseURL:nil];
        }
}


- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@end
```

When I comment the following two lines of code both **background-color** and **color** properties are working properly but when I uncomment background-color is not working at all.

```
//[webview setPaginationMode: UIWebPaginationModeLeftToRight];
//[webview setPaginationBreakingMode:UIWebPaginationBreakingModeColumn];
```